# How to record video using AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, avfoundation

Need to record the video using AVFoundation. Googled a lot but not got success. Showing the code below i used, it opens the camera but don't getting how to start recording and save it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setupCameraSession];

}

- (void)setupCameraSession
{    
ICLog;

// Session
AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];    
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080];

// Capture device
AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error;

// Device input
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
if ( [session canAddInput:deviceInput] )
    [session addInput:deviceInput];

// Preview
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];    
[previewLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(-70, 0, rootLayer.bounds.size.height, rootLayer.bounds.size.height)];
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

[session startRunning];
}
```

Please guide for above.

Answer (score -1):

To record Video with `AVFoundation`, you can use the following code:

```
-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
usingDelegate:(id )delegate {
// 1 - Validattions
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
    || (delegate == nil)
    || (controller == nil)) {
    return NO;
}
// 2 - Get image picker
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
// Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
// 3 - Display image picker
[controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
return YES;
```

}

For further explanation, you can look into this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Some of the very helpful tutorials for recording video using `AVFoundation` are :

- [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)
- [ios-developer.net](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2)

Comment: Thats Munahil but i mentioned that in the question that i need to use the AVFoundation way because my further functionality need AVFoundation only.